# Use nodeclipse plugin

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using nodeclipse plugin in eclipse to start working with nodejs and expressjs ,but when i create expressjs project and try run app.js file i get this error

```
      /home/ali/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:99
  throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.');
  ^

Error: Most middleware (like favicon) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/home/ali/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:99:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ali/node-WS/express01/app.js:18:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This means You have to install module separately. Maybe you're using latest version of expressJS.

installing modules separately will solve your problem!